# Compiler error when creating getter methods for auto synthesized properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties

After defining a property in the interface of a class, I create a setter method using the automatically generated `_property` method. Everything is going great. Then I create a getter method for the same property. As soon as I do, the compiler throws an error that `_property` is not defined everywhere that I used it.

If I have only the getter or setter defined, everything works fine, but as soon as I define both, `_property` ceases to exist.

If I add `@synthesize property = _property;` to the top of my implementation the problem is solved, but it makes me sad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal. If you declare a property, the compiler normally auto synthesizes an ivar and the getter and setter methods.

But if you explicitly define your own getter and setter methods, the compiler no longer auto generates an ivar. Your solution is to explicitly declare your own ivar. You don't need the `@synthesize` line, just declare the ivar.

The reason for this behavior is that it is quite possible to have an implementation of a property that doesn't actually use an ivar. So if you define both setter and getter, the compiler leaves it up to you to decided if the ivar is needed or not.

BTW - this is not new behavior in Xcode 4.6.2. This has been true ever since the compiler supported auto synthesized ivars.

Comment: Absolutely right, I'm not sure why I only now encountered this fact. Out of curiosity is `@synthesize property = _property` effectively the same as defining the ivar in the header?

Comment: Essentially. But you shouldn't be putting the ivar in the header. It should go in the .m file since it is private. Personally, since you are not synthesizing the getter and setter, there is no reason to synthesize the ivar. Just declare your own ivar. Then it is consistent.

Comment: Right. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!